# Is their a way to find the index of a particular value from a data frame in R?

Tags: r, data-analysis

*This is the actual problem

Q. Write a code to print the price for 3bedroom houses (each house not combined).

```
 new_data = read.csv("LR.csv")
    count = 0
    index = 1
    for(x in new_data$bedrooms){
      if(x == 3){
        count = count+1
        print(new_data$price[index])
        index = index +1
      }
    }
    print(count)


 Result of this code is:
[1] 275000
[1] 565000
[1] 460000
[1] 603500
[1] 490600
[1] 1010000
[1] 5e+05
[1] 249000
[1] 235000
[1] 410000
[1] 370000
[1] 360000
[1] 1410000
[1] 298000
[1] 485000
[1] 4e+05
[1] 580000
[1] 355000
[1] 650000
[1] 261490
[1] 347000
[1] 485000
[1] 601000
```

And many more like this. But I want to find exactly which property is it by either it's index number or id.

> For the file please reply "file" and give your contact method like mail id or SNS id. I will send you the file.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `which( x == y )`

Comment: By using `dput(new_data)` and copying the output code, you can share the data without needing to send files around.

Comment: Don't try to solve tasks in R using the same approaches as you would use in C++ ...

Answer (score 0):

You could use `which()` to get the row indices of the rows fullfilling your condition:

```
idx <- which(new_data$bedrooms == 3)
print(new_data$price[idx]) # just printing the price
print(new_data[idx,] # printing the whole row
```

Or you could just directly get the results with slicing based on a condition:

```
print(new_data$price[new_data$bedrooms == 3] # just printing the price
print(new_data[new_data$bedrooms == 3,] # printing the whole row
```